# Set position inside Window libgdx

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to position actors inside a Window, but when trying to set a fixed position, the settings to seem to affect the ui properly.

I've tried putting a Table inside the window, which works as you would expect, but when trying to call

```
myactor.setPosition(10,10);
window.add(myactor);
```

the actor is not affected by the position.
Is there any way to do that, or do widgets in window have to be added as in a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window is table that can be dragged and act as a modal window. Table is a WidgetGroup that sets the position and size of its children using a logical table, similar to HTML tables.

Table-based layouts don't rely on absolute positioning and therefore automatically adjust to different widget sizes and screen resolutions.

Take a look of [Table](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table#overview) to set position of your Actor.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set the Actors position inside a Scene2d Window. I know its an old topic but I thought I would rebuff Aryan's answer.

You need to use the following method:

```
window.setLayoutEnabled(false)
```

Then, set the Actors position:

```
window.findActor("someActorName").setPosition(x,y);
```

This basically disables the default window Layout, so any actor you add to the Window will be set to the Windows' own coordinate system.

I tested the method and it works.

See the LibGDX Window Api:
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Window.html